# How to force a new child window position in Gtk Overlay?

Tags: gtk

I have connected a signal via "get-child-position" and the child is positioned correctly. But now how can i make this signal get called again when i want to show the child at a different position?

Comment: Is it correct, that it's _you_ who calculates `GdkRectangle` for allocation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found it, its a simple call to "gtk_widget_queue_resize(widget)"